# How to format Number of json object and set it in TextView Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, illegalargumentexception

I'm Developing an app that fetches data from JSON. I want to set the int number into TextView in Formatted Way. I used Java java.text.NumberFormat for Formating.I want data to be Like 100000 = 1,00,000.

But This Giving error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
```

Here is my code

```
 String myString = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(jsonObject.getString("cases"));
 totalCasesNum.setText(myString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String myString = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("cases"));
```